# Relative import

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to make a dynamic relative import in Python but i'm not sure how to do it. My project is organized like this :

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── requests.py
└── serializers.py
```

and I need to do the equivalent of `from .serializers import Serializer`.

I tried multiple time with `__import__`, `imp` and `importlib` but I'm not even sure it's possible.

Edit: I got it working by doing `__import__('serializers', globals(), locals(), [], 1).Serializer`

Comment: Can you show what you tried? Did you see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)?

Comment: It depends where you are importing from. If you are in `requests.py` then your code should work, as you are traversing back to the parent node, then accessing the `serializers` module.

Comment: `importlib.import_module('.serializers.GET_Serializer)` gives `the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '.serializers.GET_Serializer'` I could not find a second argument to make him happy

Comment: @Seiji, I'm importing from `requests.py` indeed

Comment: `imp.find_module('.serializers.GET_Serializer')` gives `No module named '.serializers.GET_Serializer'`

Comment: isn't `GET_Serializer` a method and not a module?